# What is $|\{\{1, 2, 3\}\}|?$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is $|\{\{1, 2, 3\}\}|?$

Solution:

So that symbol is cardinality meaning size, would it be one because there is only one set in the set?

$|\{\{1, 2, 3\}\}| = 1$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a tricky question. Your set $\{\{1,2,3\}\}$ only contains one element. This element is the set $\{1,2,3\}$.

If this confuses you just denote $a:=\{1,2,3\}$ and then the first set becomes $\{a\}$.